# Netbeans and source folders

Tags: java, netbeans

I am working on a large project and I have configured multiple source package folders.

```
Project -> Properties -> Sources
```

However, when I import a library from this other source folder it says it doesn't exist so obviously with source folder is only liked in during compile time.

How do I get my project to reference these source files to work within my project without creating class files etc, and keeping both source directories separate from one another?

Thanks

Comment: By importing the library, do you mean that you added it in Project >> Properties >> Libraries ?

Comment: just Project -> Properties -> Sources. Libraries relates just to jar files.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you wish to make the source files from one NetBeans (Java Application) project *A* visible in another like project *B*.

In project *B*:

1. Go to Properties >> Libraries
2. Go to the Libraries category
3. Go to the Compile tab
4. Choose 'Add Project...' and select project *A*.

Regardless of whether the sources in *A* have been compiled, you should then be able to use them (e.g., name auto-complete, javadoc peek) when editing source code in *B*.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure package names are correctly defined!